# Im trying to group two queries by year so that it will show the amount of tours done(by count of tour id) in that year

Tags: ms-access

```
SELECT [school tours done showing year].[CountOfTour ID], 
       [Visitor Tours Done Showing Year].[CountOfTour ID],
       Year([Date]) AS [Year]
FROM   [school tours done showing year], [Visitor Tours Done Showing Year];
```

Comment: It might help to show the two queries....

Comment: And, are you currently showing us actual code of some sort, or pseudo-code? I would expect you to need to use the `COUNT` function somewhere, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming [Date] contains "year" values (i.e. 2018, 2017, 2016, ..)

```
;With SchoolTours AS 
(
SELECT [Date] AS YEAR, COUNT(ID) AS [SchoolCountOfTour ID] 
FROM [school tours done showing year] 
GROUP BY [Date]
)
, VisitorTours AS
(
SELECT [Date] AS YEAR, COUNT(ID) AS [VisitorCountOfTour ID] 
FROM [Visitor Tours Done Showing Year]
GROUP BY [Date]
)
SELECT t1.Year
, t1.[SchoolCountOfTour ID] 
, t2.[VisitorCountOfTour ID]
FROM SchoolTours t1
LEFT JOIN VisitorTours t2 ON t2.Year = t1.Year
```

Plenty of other ways to do it but I'm partial to CTEs

B

Comment: Notice the ms-access tag on the question.  CTEs don't apply, invalid syntax.

Comment: Oh, good spot - no I never noticed, still getting to grips with this and not quite yet there when it comes to checking various important clues!
Now I'm hoping that the OP will know how to convert those CTEs into "normal" sub queries!